# How to update correct text input values in a nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and got a problem. I got a big a object that will contain a lot of logic for the application I am trying to build.

Based on this object I am trying to render inputfields and also update the corresponding records in the object. I got a [Codesandbox with my problem setup here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-sutherland-3qbym?file=/src/App.js:0-1121).

I got my 'top level' component that holds the object and passes it down to its children:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Content from "./Content";

export default function App() {
  const [formDocument, setFormDocument] = useState({
    document: {
      content: {
        sections: [
          {
            additionalFields: true,
            destroyable: false,
            key: "personalDetails",
            moveable: false,
            fields: [
              {
                fieldType: "text",
                key: "name",
                linkedFieldsKey: "name"
              },
              {
                fieldType: "text",
                key: "emailAddress",
                linkedFieldsKey: "emailAddress"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        records: [{ key: "1", values: ["Tim", "tim@gmail.com"] }]
      }
    }
  });

  const updateDocument = (e) => {
    //how do I update the corresponding records for the inputfields?
    console.log("inputfield is updated");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Content {...formDocument} updateDoc={(e) => updateDocument(e)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now I got a child that uses the formDocument object called `Content.jsx` and I want to update the corresponding `records` in the `formDocument` object. This is the `Content.jsx`:

```
export default function Content({ updateDoc, ...formDocument }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "10px" }}
        type="text"
        value={formDocument.document.content.records[0].values[0]}
        onChange={(e) => updateDoc(e)}
      />

      <input
        style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "10px" }}
        type="text"
        value={formDocument.document.content.records[0].values[1]}
        onChange={(e) => updateDoc(e)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I update the correct records without making a function for each and every inputfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think that you should spit the States but the code for this goes as follows :-

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Content from "./Content";

export default function App() {
  const [formDocument, setFormDocument] = useState({
    document: {
      content: {
        sections: [
          {
            additionalFields: true,
            destroyable: false,
            key: "personalDetails",
            moveable: false,
            fields: [
              {
                fieldType: "text",
                key: "name",
                linkedFieldsKey: "name"
              },
              {
                fieldType: "text",
                key: "emailAddress",
                linkedFieldsKey: "emailAddress"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        records: [{ key: "1", values: ["Tim", "tim@gmail.com"] }]
      }
    }
  });

  const updateDocument = (e, index) => {
    //how do I update the corresponding records for the inputfields?
    let new_document = {...formDocument};
    new_document['document']['content']['records'][0]['values'][index]=e.target.value;
    setFormDocument(new_document);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Content {...formDocument} updateDoc={updateDocument} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Content.js

```
export default function Content({ updateDoc, ...formDocument }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {formDocument.document.content.records[0].values.map((elem, i) => (
        <input
          style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "10px" }}
          type="text"
          value={elem}
          onChange={(e) =>
            updateDoc(e,i)
          }
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do you say you recommend splitting the state? What is your reasoning behind that? Also, what is the difference between `updateDoc={updateDocument}` you used in your code and my original: `updateDoc={(e) => updateDocument(e)}`? Thanks in advance :).

Comment: No difference between `updateDoc={updateDocument}` and `updateDoc={(e) => updateDocument(e)}` but `updateDoc={updateDocument}` is much more cleaner.

Comment: Splitting your code makes it easier for reusability and readability. `new_document['document']['content']['records'][0]['values']` seems unnecessary if you can simply boil it down to a simple `array`

Comment: Thank you for answer but i had an issue when using that style its about; when state is update, my view also update but cause of this input will be un-focused. Maybe I need to create a component for that row.

Answer (score 1):

When updating an object/array in React, you have to make sure you update it with a "new" item. For doing that, you could create a copy like this:

```
const arrayCopy = [...array]
const objectCopy = {...object}
```

By updating the state using the same object or array, React won't kow that element has been updated.

So for example, if you have this in the state:

```
const [document, setDocument] = useState({
  users: [
    { name: 'Peter', email: 'hi@peter.com' },
    { name: 'Michael', email: 'hi@michael.com' },
  ]
})
```

Then I would follow these steps in order to update the state properly:

```
// Create a copy of the object in the state
let updatedObject = {...document}

// Update it as needed
let newUsers = [...document.users]
newUsers[1].name = 'Manolo'

const updatedObject = {
  ...document,
  users: [...newUsers]
}

// Update the state with a copy of the new object
// For doing so, I'd pass a function callback
setUsers(() => ({ ...updatedObject }))
```

That should make rerender your component and see the changes.

---

I would also reorganize the state a little bit. Split it when needed, you can use more than one state variable. That will help you locate the errors and debug it better. Also improves readability and will let you write better code.

Comment: This still mutates the user object itself. To avoid it you should spread the mutated object as well `newUsers[1] = {...newUsers[1], name:  'Manolo'}`